# Linux Mint 13 connected to lan but not to internet

Tags: networking, linux-mint

I've had a computer running linux mint 13 for about 6 months now without any problems. Every time that I tried to connect to the internet I just used a standard ethernet port and had no problems connecting to the internet. Now this week when I moved back into my college apartment the computer suddenly will no longer connect to the internet. The computer connects to the lan no problem and I can access it my computer.

The computer is connected to the internet by a switch to a router to the modem. I know that the switch and router and modem works because every single other device (something like 12-14 devices between wifi and wired) all can get to the internet and talk to each other on the lan no problem simultaneously. There are two other computers on the switch which both have internet access.

So my question is, does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you try to change the MAC address of the Ethernet adapter to an address you know works (maybe from another laptop)? Don't know if it is possible on Linux, but I had a similar situation with a laptop running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in LMDE 201403. It worked perfectly for several weeks and suddenly stopped connecting to the internet. Other laptops running the same OS is connecting properly to the internet (so it is not router or DSL issue). After spending a day, I found out that `/etc/resolv.conf` got messed up by the SonicWall netExtender (during sleep/wake cycle). The last line haD binary characters. I deleted that line and added the IP address of my router in `/etc/resolv.conf` as shown below and it started working again.

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

When this problem happened, I was able to ping using the physical IP address but not to any external hostnames like `www.google.com`.